# cannot import tensorflow - "Import Error: cannot import name 'self_check' "

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm trying to use tensorflow-gpu. Using Anaconda, I installed the libraries and active both (tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu) I have also installed Keras in this anaconda environment as well

Next I launch Spider IDE within my Anaconda environment and run my py script, that is when I get the following error:

cannot import tensorflow - Import Error: cannot import name 'self_check'

I'm totally lost. Any recommendations? 
Using Python 3.5

Thanks

Comment: Add some more details including how you installed and what exactly error you are getting

Comment: Please see description. I edited to be a bit more specific

Answer (score 2):

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

or

you can uninstall the tensorflow and re-install it.